# Unable to locate workflow running on Case

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, case, case-object

When I edit a Case Contact from community portal and change the value in Contact of that Case, it changes to previous entered value and is not updated. But when I check the Field history tracking of Contact field on Case, it shows that Contact is updated to new value and reverted back to same value.
For Example :
Suppose on Case Contact : 'user1'  and i change to 'user2' then when i checked that case Contact it is having value: 'user1'. But when i checked field history tracking of  Contact field on Case it shows : Contact changes to 'user2' and again it changes back to 'user1'  .

I have deactivated all the Workflows, Triggers, Validation Rules, Assigment rules on Case Object but when i checked Debug logs it shows some workfolw is running. I am unable to locate how it is happennig.

```
**DEBUG LOGS:**

03:00:20.111 (111407252)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[61]|ApexPages.StandardController.getRecord()
03:00:20.111 (111443528)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[61]|String.valueOf(Object)
03:00:20.111 (111548706)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[61]|String.valueOf(Object)
03:00:20.111 (111576404)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[61]|System.debug(ANY)
03:00:20.111 (111587589)|USER_DEBUG|[61]|DEBUG|*** casCase:{Status=Implementation in Progress, Description=sx322323, RecordTypeId=012400000009eIiAAI, Subject=ss2323, ContactId=003e000000Lx9gZAAR, Id=500e0000004ylyhAAA, CaseNumber=00009865, Priority=E3}
03:00:20.111 (111598033)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[61]|System.debug(ANY)
03:00:20.111 (111612692)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[63]|EnhancementNewTicketController.__sfdc_cas()
03:00:20.111 (111639294)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[63]|EnhancementNewTicketController.__sfdc_cas()
03:00:20.111 (111662534)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[63]|ApexPages.StandardController.save()
03:00:20.111 (111723268)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
03:00:20.111 (111771197)|DML_BEGIN|[63]|Op:ControllerSave|Type:Case|Rows:1
03:00:20.286 (286943171)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Case
03:00:20.313 (313443907)**|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Assignment
03:00:20.313 (313473272)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Assignment
03:00:20.313 (313479502)|WF_ACTION|.
03:00:20.313 (313483428)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
03:00:20.313 (313538064)|WF_ACTIONS_END| None**
03:00:20.313 (313544727)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Case
**03:00:20.315 (315547615)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|SLA
03:00:20.320 (320099915)|SLA_PROCESS_CASE|500e0000004ylyh
03:00:20.348 (348195905)|SLA_END|Cases:1&#124;LoadTime:5&#124;ProcTime:28&#124;CM CUD:0&#124;0&#124;0&#124;New Trigger:0
03:00:20.348 (348215776)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|SLA**
03:00:20.350 (350755647)|DML_END|[63]
03:00:20.350 (350845952)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[63]|ApexPages.StandardController.save()
03:00:20.350 (350962714)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[69]|System.PageReference.setRedirect(Boolean)
03:00:20.351 (351013896)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[69]|System.PageReference.setRedirect(Boolean)
03:00:20.428 (428835211)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|EnhancementNewTicketController invoke(SAVE1)
03:00:20.429 (429852927)|VF_APEX_CALL|j_id24|{!SAVE1}|PageReference:/tantacomm/apex/ListViewTickets
03:00:20.615 (432284239)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
03:00:20.615|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

Comment: Do you have any apps installed?

Comment: Yes a number of apps are installed

Comment: Workflow might be in an app - I would call support if I were you - they should be able to tell you which app.

Comment: @SachinArora Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue. I deactivated all the triggers, workflow and process builders but still contactId field is getting updated with the logged in community user's related contact Id.